# Calllog plugin for iOS not available

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic2

We are trying to get the Call Logs in ionic hybrid mobile app for both android and iOS. But the cordova plugins available supports android only. Can you please suggest me how to get the call logs in a hybrid app?

Also I see **Truecaller** app has that functionality. Is there anyone who knows how truecaller has retrieved those call logs?

Comment: You cannot access the caller log on iOS.  It is not available to apps for privacy reasons.  Truecaller does not access the call log.  It implements the call blocking features available in iOS 10 and allows users to send numbers to TrueCaller in order to report spam numbers

Comment: Thanks for your information @Paulw11. Is there any plugin or way to capture the event once a caller ends the call?

Comment: No, apps have no access to call logs.